# Django - форма поиска

Tags: django

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно посмотреть реализацию формы поиска такого типа, например:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    keywords = models.CharField()
```

Есть вьюха с формой создания объекта Place, при этом keywords это строка из слов, разделенных запятой.

Задача - создать вьюху с формой поиска объектов по имени и ключевым словам, которые также будут вноситься как слова, разделенные запятой.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Если вы хотите искать по двум полям модели в одном поле формы, можно использовать объект `Q` с оператором `|`, что означает `or`
views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.db.models import Q

class PlaceListView(ListView):
    model = Place

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Получаем не отфильтрованный кверисет всех моделей
        queryset = super(FlavorListView, self).get_queryset()
        q = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if q:
        # Если 'q' в GET запросе, фильтруем кверисет по данным из 'q'
            return queryset.filter(Q(name__icontains=q)|
                                   Q(keywords__icontains=q))
        return queryset
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
'',
url(r'^place_search/$', PlaceListView.as_view, name='place_search'),)
```

Форма в шаблоне:

```
<form action="{% url "place_search" %}" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <button type="submit">search</button>
</form>
<!--> Сюда можно включить шаблон с результатами через include
      Или выделить для него отдельный блок <-->
{% include "template/result_template.html" %}
```

Шаблон с результатами формы поиска:

```
<h1>Places</h1>
<ul>
{% for place in object_list %}
    <li>{{ place.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**UPD**
Если вы хотите искать вхождение каждого слова, через запятую, можно разбить строку в список и искать вхождение в нем.

```
....
q = self.request.GET.get("q")
q_lst = q.split(",")
return queryset.filter(Q(name__in=q_lst)|
                       Q(keywords__in=q_lst))
```

Comment: смотрите какая ситуация - при создании объекта в поле keywords пойдет строка (напр. "спам,еггс,хам").. я хочу получать этот объект при поиске даже если в форме будет введено например только "спам" или "фигня, спам" и т.п. .. может я не прав, но по Вашему коду мне кажется, что будет идти неверное сравнение (через contains).. т.е. код будет проверять, что "фигня, спам" есть в "спам,еггс,хам"... или я не прав?

Comment: @Dennis да все верно, `i__contains` ищет полное вхождение слово, можно так же добавить поиск по отдельным словам, предварительно сделав из них список. Сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: спасибо, Иван! направление понял :) но все же есть вопрос - получается, что Q(keywords__in=q_lst) будет искать по-моему таким образом - например, если при создании объекта юзер определил в поле keywords "spam, eggs", то при поиске, при вводе в форму "spam,eggs,some,any" начнется поиск типа "spam,eggs" in ['spam', 'eggs', 'some', 'any'] ... мне же нужно, чтобы сопоставляло каждое слово в keywords каждому слову в форме.. т.е. выдавало объект даже при совпадении одного слова